# Transforming impluse to DC Current

Tags: 555, monostable

I have a source of power in form of a single impulse (around 40V for a fraction of a second), I need to convert it to a constant 12v for a longer time (like a tenth of a second) to power a small IC. I've searched through the forum with little luck, I thought to use a 555 Monostable but it needs a Vcc that I don't have, what I'd ideally need is something to do both the trigger work and the Vcc. I know it's already been done, I just need to be pointed to the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: A capacitor, perhaps? You really need to expand on what your application is.

Comment: You need to define "fraction of a second", and I_small_IC. But an input diode to a capacitor and a 12V regulator from cap does the job. Regulator must tolderate 40V + in. and cap must be able to charge from pulse in available time. Telling us what you are wanting to do and NOT how you think it may be dome is a better idea. (If you knew HOW you'd do it).

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a capacitor to store the energy and some kind of regulator to adjust the voltage. Depending on your source a diode on the input to prevent the energy to flow back.

For the regulator you can choose an linear one, if you want to have it simple and cheap and if you don't mind to loose a big part of the energy provided by the pulse. 
If your circuit should work as long as possible with a single feeding pulse, you may want to choose a DC-DC regulator. They are more complicated to build but will allow you to use the power much better.